# How does Kuchiki Rukia gain her Bankai?

Tags: anime, bleach

I have seen that Rukia fights using his bankai named Hakka no Togame, but I do not recall background info about how develop this form. Is there  any information in the manga or anime?

Comment: i think you should be asked this on Anime and manga stack exchange

Comment: Im pretty sure after the first attack by the quincy she goes to were the king lives forgot what its called. And there she learns to release her bankia i believe she mentions that at one point but i dont remember were jn the manga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**; Rukia and Renji upon almost dying during the quincy attack on soul society, They are taken to the soul kings palace, healed and given advanced training.

> Later, Senjumaru Shutara brings Rukia, Renji, and Byakuya to the Royal Guard's Tenchūren so they can be taken to the Royal Palace. Unohana states their condition is too critical for them to leave Seireitei, but the Royal Guard insist on taking them.
>
> She eventually recovers completely, and goes to Senjumaru's palace with Renji for clothing measurements, in which she and Renji are forced to strip down. After they conclude their business there, they move on to Ichibē Hyōsube's palace to begin training. There, they note the extreme difficulty of moving, with Rukia comparing the Reishi around her to water

[bleach wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Rukia_Kuchiki)